# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, qlpreviewcontroller

When I am presenting a **QLPreviewviewcontrolelr** from my **Viewcontroller**, the runtime warning that appears in the log as

**Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for .**

Can anyone please suggest me the solution to fix.

Comment: where you present this QLPreview on under with  which method

Comment: I have one method for showing Info, When we tap on that Info button I need to display a pdf document.

Comment: Expecting MoreAnswers from this Forum !!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you delete main.m file?If you didn't have an application begin,you will get this.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly Apple bug. You can wrap preview controller into navigation controller and then present this navigation controller modally. This seems to work fine. Only then you'll have to dismiss it manually.

```
let picker = QLPreviewController()
picker.dataSource = self
picker.delegate = self

let navcon = UINavigationController(rootViewController: picker)

presentViewController(navcon, animated: true, completion: { 
           picker.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(MyViewController.dismiss(_:))) })
```